# Axios POST Request with CSFR Token gets denied - 401

Tags: javascript, post, axios, token

My Axios Post request is getting denied with 401, I'm not sure what is causing it, the CSRF token should be correct.

```
   await axios.post(url, {
          withCredentials: true,
          params: {
            json: true,
          },
          auth: {
            username: 'stack',
            password: 'overflow'
          },
          headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            "X-CSRF-Token": csfrToken
          }
        })
```

[image]

Comment: We can't tell why the server is rejecting it. We can't see the server side code. (And that's assuming it is the POST request getting the 401 and not a preflight options request that you didn't mention).

Comment: I can't see the server code myself, because I'm sending this to OData of a SAP System. How can I check the preflight options? I havent configured anything

Comment: You've added non-standard headers. That configuration will trigger a preflight. The Network tab of the browser's developer tools will show you what request you are sending.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where I can find the preflight headers, I editet the original post with a screenshot from the request tab of the developer tools

Comment: `X-Requested-With` and `X-CSRF-Token` are *both* non-standard headers that will trigger a preflight. `withCredentials` will trigger a preflight.

Comment: And how or where can I actually see this preflight?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was I had to take the cookies which I get from my GET request where I fetch the csfr token and pass them with my POST request.